# Geometric distribution-Calculation of probability of success

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I know that the question might be very basic and silly, but I need some help on understanding the basics.

I saw a question on geometric distribution.

A bank is reviewing its telephone banking division and tries to find how soon/easily a customer can talk to a phone-banking officer. When a customer calls, the phone rings for 12 times before getting to the call-back services.

An experiment is conducted with 5 people and the number of calls made to reach the banking officer is recorded.(they are asked to retry if the call-back service is reached).The number of calls made to reach the banking officer is recorded for each participant and are as follows:

- 5
- 0
- 1
- 0
- 0

In this experiment, what is the probability of success(p of a geometric distribution)? Is it 1/2 (because it is equally likely to reach the officer as reaching the call back service) or is it 3/5( 3 participants out of 5 have reached the bank officer in the first attempt without any failure) ?

Geometric distribution used for modeling the number of failures until the first success:

Pr(Y = k) = p*(1-p)^k where k =1,2,3 and p = probability of success

Comment: See [this introductory note](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on posting with mathematical expressions.  It will help make your posts understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the geometric distribution as the number of failures until the first success then it is defined for $k \geq 0$. A possible way of estimating the $p$ is by the method of moments.

You know that your distribution is a $X ~ Geo(p)$ wso its mean is $EX = 1/p-1$. You can find the mean for your sample and by equating to that of $X$ get an estimating for $p$.

Be aware that you can only estimate $p$, not find it.